# To capture Tv tuner/webcam output

Tags: device-driver

We are developting a tool for live video streaming in which we want to broadcast the output of tv tuner on a network.Our project is at it's nascent stage.Our main concern at this moment is to how to capture the output of a tv tuner card.Plz guide us regarding this or provide a pointer where I can detail about the topic.
All help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks 
Mawia

ps:project is for cross-platform but at the moment even if you tell me of any one platform it will be enough!

Comment: Do you have a platform in mind? Device drivers, by their very nature, tend to be platform-specific.

Comment: yeah i should have mentioned that.actually the project is for cross-platform but at this moment you can tell me for linux/unix based.thanks

Answer (score 1):

With Linux, Ubuntu specifically, a webcam's audio and video are mounted on /dev/audioX and /dev/videoY, where x and y are numbers. It can be a bit tricky to find out where the system has mounted the device, if more then one is present, however a quick 'ls /dev | grep audio' and 'ls /dev | grep video' should help narrow the search.

As for tv tuners I am unsure, though it seems likely that they would also be mounted under /dev.